# Can't access login page, 404 not found

Tags: admin, url-rewrite, 404

I have recently moved my magento installation from one server to another and have had some issues with the urls not being found. I was able to solve this temporarily but using `/index.php/admin` and then turning of the URL rewrites. This allowed to me access all my files including the login page. However when messing around with some setting (URL rewrites) included i am no unable to access my admin page again. I can however access all other pages.

The admin page can be accessed using `/index.php/admin` BUT it simply refreshes the page instead of logging me in.

Anybody else had this problem and or know what is wrong ?

Comment: Update: I imported the original database again and turned the rewrite rule off, cleared cache then re-indexed. Everything seamed to be working as expected then a few hours later i get the same problem. I am at a loss as to what could cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i believe i have found the solution. Before i get to the answer i feel it is important to state that this magento installation was transferred from a professional webhotell provider to a private server that was set up by a inexperienced user (me). Ok on to the solution.

**Solution:** I made a minor change to the code in the httpd.conf file

```
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The line of code that was changed was..

**from** this: `AllowOverride None`

**to** this: `AllowOverride All`

Admittedly not i understand this fully but it appears to have made all the difference and i hope this can help others in a similar situation.